# Change only when compatible with a single word

Tags: php, replace

If the words in the text are compatible with the words in the `Array`, the words are `class` adding.

```
$searchArray = array('settings all','print', 'sum', 'industry', ...); // total 50K words


function sanitize($string) {
    global $searchArray;
    $repl = array_map("dashReplace", $searchArray);
    $string = str_replace($searchArray, $repl, $string);

    return $string;
}

function dashReplace($str) {
    return "<span class='txtOlg'>" . $str . "</span>";
}

echo sanitize($text);
```

*Result:*

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettings all
>   industry.

*HTML Format:*

```
Lorem Ip<span class='txtOlg'>sum</span> is simply dummy text of the <span class='txtOlg'>print</span>ing and type<span class='txtOlg'>settings all</span> industry.    
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If there is a match in the word it changes but I don't want it to change. For example;

*HTML Format:*

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettings all <span class='txtOlg'>industry</span>.
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What do I need to do to change it if it is compatible with a single word? *(not compatibility for words)*

Comment: Why down-vote ?

Comment: Didn't downvote. Issue is that yours is considering the substring as a correct match. A regex word boundary should do good.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, can Regex cause slow performance? @vivek_23

Comment: You will have to do some benchmarking, but IMO, it should be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is occurring because it's matching a substring as well. To avoid this, you can use [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to replace all patterns(as in words in regex format from `$searchArray`) with your `$repl` array on `$string` as the subject.

```
<?php

$searchArray = array('settings all','print', 'sum', 'industry'); // total 50K words


function sanitize($string,$searchArray) {
    $repl = array_map("dashReplace", $searchArray);
    $pattern = array_map("insertWordBoundaries", $searchArray);
    $string = preg_replace($pattern,$repl,$string);
    return $string;
}

function dashReplace($str) {
    return "<span class='txtOlg'>" . $str . "</span>";
}

function insertWordBoundaries($str){
    return "/\b". preg_quote($str,"/") ."\b/";
}

$text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesettings all industry.';
echo sanitize($text,$searchArray);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/2gved

**Update #1:**

Also, using global variables inside method definitions are bad, especially in the OOP context. Your style is procedural, but I would still recommend passing `$searchArray` as an extra parameter, so it's like a perfectly reusable piece. Otherwise, we are making it static to only use global `$searchArray` always.

**Update #2:**

We perform a regex match on each word by adding a word boundary `\b` on both sides of a string.

Quoting from [Regex tutorials](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

> The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign.
>   It matches at a position that is called a “word boundary”. This match
>   is zero-length.
>
> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: Thank you so much but I getting this error: I'm getting `SearchArray` from a different PHP file. So at first I import the file (`include "TermList.php";`). Error: `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'b' in ..` Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: @Emre5 So do an `include_once("TermList.php");` in your code. Also, for unknown modifier issue, are you sure you have added the slash `\`  before and after the string?

Comment: I added it to [PasteBIN](https://pastebin.com/MgcfCryA) to explain it better. Yes I'm sure for slash. I've been careful.

Comment: @Emre5 What is your PHP version?

Comment: PHP Version 7.3.10

Comment: @Emre5 Add a `return "/\b". preg_quote($str,'/') ."\b/";` to your code.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough! You helped my question and also helped with the error caused by the version difference. **Thank you for your time**

Comment: @Emre5 Glad I could help. Actually, the error was not due to version difference but rather because of the contents of some words. Hope the solution is performant with 50K words.

Comment: This is English-Turkish dictionary. I don't see any slow at this time. For now:) Thank you again.

Comment: @Emre5 That sounds great. I just updated my answer with the `preg_quote()` for people who would refer to this answer in future :)